# Multiple PCIe Controllers

Tags: ssd, raid, pci-express

I am trying to exceed the 6Gb/s barrier of SATA3 I want to use RAID 0 on multiple SSD's and I am trying to come up with a (relatively inexpensive solution) I have 40 available PCIe lanes /16 are being used (video card) on an MSI x99s motherboard 
I am considering add 2 Sata3 controllers with 2 ports each and attempt to raid the attached drives.

I am unsure what other concerns I may have. the data bus should clearly be able to handle it. here are my questions.

would there be limitation in the processor or the PCIe controller or anything else I'm not considering?

Am i doing this totally wrong is there another solution I am unaware of?

so I wanted to make this a little more specific there are 12Gb/s raid controllers but they are at minimum $250 for a 2 port controller and I need a 4 port to achieve the desired affect 250 I want to do 2 2 port 6Gb/s controllers and use software raid to run them. I can get a 2 port PCIe 6Gb/s raid controller for about $20 hence the inexpensive solution.

if there is another way to exceed 6Gb/s this will not be running an operating system and will be backed up to another drive so I am not concerned at all about reliability.

Comment: You're doing this totally wrong. ;)  Get a good single hardware RAID controller and use that instead of software RAID (which you'll be stuck with if you try to build a RAID across multiple SATA controllers).  As-is this question is too broad (IMO at least).

Comment: I did find a couple of raid controllers http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816117402 but they are extremely expensive

Comment: You are asking to do something that is beyond the basic components available today. So the ide aof doing this "on the cheap" is basically not going to happen.  If each drive is 6Gb/s max, you're not going to pull data any faster than that, RAID or otherwise.  If you really want it faster, skip SATA, bust our your wallet, and buy some [12GB/s SAS SSD drives](http://www.seagate.com/ca/en/internal-hard-drives/solid-state-hybrid/1200-ssd/) - they're currently ONLY $2500-3000 for a 800GB drives.

Comment: At your price point, you're not going to achieve anything even close to what you're suggesting you want. So if you want to go multiple SATA controllers and software raid, then DO IT, and if you run into any specific problems along the way come back with specific questions. Again, as-is this question is just too broad.

Comment: I think you’re confusing some things. This controller is a SAS 12Gb/s controller, hence the name. This doesn’t make it any better or worse for SATA 6Gb/s. A [suitable controller](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816118233) is available for as little as $175.

Comment: Isn't it better to go with NVMe? Samsung states it's doing pretty well: http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/file/product/XS1715_ProdOverview_2014_1.pdf and drives itself are not that expensive: http://www.scan.co.uk/products/400gb-intel-dc-p3500-nvme-25-pcie-30-x4-20nm-mlc-read-2200mb-s-write-1000mb-s-420k-read-23k-write-io?utm_source=google+shopping&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=Cj0KEQjwstaqBRCT38DWpZjJotIBEiQAERS6_MM69i5o22gtO1pfS1glqiyqSSJZ84HA_fa_4_kFYdcaAn1W8P8HAQ

Comment: bah nm Im just buying the 12gb/s card

Comment: thanks for your advice guys I think I got all the information I needed.

Answer (score 0):

questions:
would there be limitation in the processor or the PCIe controller or anything else I'm not considering? No. the only limitation is that you are force to use software raid.which can be unreliable at times however since they are SSD's they are more reliable than with physical drives. however be sure to backup data.

Am i doing this totally wrong is there another solution I am unaware of?
Yes. the proper method would to be use a single hardware raid controller for the entire array. however this is a much cheaper alternative with limitations.